# How do I change the normal view color to sepia color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to change the background color of a view when `UISwitch` is ON. When `UIswitch` is OFF, it should show the normal color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First launch your DigitalColorMeter application in your macbook. Select particular area in your image, (by focusing through your cursor). It will give you RGB value for that. Here is the pictorial view for that.

[image]

Hope this will make your task easier.

Please reply.

Answer (score 1):

Sepia color is RGB(112, 66, 20).
That is why you can use next expression:

```
 myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:112/255.0 green:66/255.0 blue:20/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `backgroundColor` property of `UIView`.

```
myView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor greenColor];
```

Would suggest you to explore the documentation supplied by Apple.

[Here is documentation for UIView.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Comment: Not like this. I want to change that to sepia color. do u understand?

Comment: @sathiamoorthy: you could create any color by it's RGBA values.

Comment: Do u know how to change the UIimage color with RGBA values

Comment: Are you trying to use a sepia effect on your images? If so, re-write your question to indicate that. You’ve asked how to change the background color, which is what these answers show you.

Comment: Sorry for that, Can u tell me how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any mockup image or sample color, then you can use ***DigitalColor Meter*** application. This is an in-built application available in *Mac OS*. Just select you color available on screen (If you have opened any image then select particular area), it will show you exact ***RGB*** values for that color of selected area.

Then you can use those values in

```
UIColor *c = [UIColor colorWithRed:(<red value>/255.0) green:(<green value>/255.0) blue:(<blue value>/255.0) alpha:alpha];
```

Hope this is what you are in search for.

Let me know whether its helpful to you or not.

Comment: Why do you think so? Please explain. Have you tried with DigitalColorMeter application?